# C++ Class Translation Design

Tags: c++

I have class A and class B. And I have two functions:

`B FromAToB(A)`
and
`A FromBToA(B)`

The question is: In which class should I implement these functions? Or they should belong in another class? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: There's no "One True Answer".  Q: Why not just write a pair of simple functions?  Why do they have to belong to a class?

Comment: Are these functions designed to convert from one type to the other?

Comment: Yes, they are converter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... there are a variety of ways to do this depending on your needs and intentions. If each function is designed to perform a destructive conversion from one type to the other, my recommendation would be to to create an operator on the type you're converting from and note somehow that it's destructive. This is pretty subjective though as you could do it the other way and I can't think of any reason it would be less valid, just most conventions of converting from type A to type B place the operator on type A (see things like toString in C#).

If the conversion is to be non-destructive, i.e. you're taking A and making a B based on A without harming A, then there are two really good ways to do this: typecasting operators or constructors. My personal recommendation is a constructor for each type that takes the other type. `A::A(const &B)` is a constructor that will take a B and make an A from it. This tends to be the most clear on what is happening and potential performance costs of doing this conversion a lot.

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea putting it in the constructor. I think I am going to implement that way.

Comment: @HuyPham: In C++11, marking a function as destructive is done by indicating it may move from `this`: `B A::convertToB() &&;` => note the `&&` after the method declaration, [see here](http://ideone.com/3ebpfX) and note how the line for `notAllowed` provoked a compilation error because the object `a` is not a temporary.

Answer (score 2):

Where to put these functions is determined by how you would use them.

As commented by @FoggyDay, there's no "One True Answer". For me, simple functions will do all.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide mutual conversion operators. This will require you to forward declare one class and defer the implementation of the conversion operator to after the implementation of the other class. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Seconds;
struct Minutes
{
    int value;
    operator Seconds() const;
};

struct Seconds
{
    int value;
    operator Minutes() const
    {
        return Minutes{value / 60};
    }
};

Minutes::operator Seconds() const
{
    return Seconds{value * 60};
}

int main()
{
    Minutes m{1};
    Seconds s{60};
    std::cout << static_cast<Seconds>(m).value << " "
              << static_cast<Minutes>(s).value;
    return 0;
}
```

If you don't want implicit conversions (to avoid mistakes) you can add `explicit` to the operators.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to code. Type casting is a nice idea. +1 for that. I will keep it in mind for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you may redefine cast operators to your type in each class you need.

For example, instead of calling functions (FromAToB etc) in A class you can do this:

```
operator B() {
  // Creating B b_object
  return b_object;
}
```

And then use it in the code

```
main() {
  // Creating A a_object
  B b_object = (B)a_object;
}
```

And vice-versa. So, there is no need to define special method for that, you may simply use type casts.

Some useful link: [Overloading typecasts](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/)